# Save given answers time to time in online exam system

Tags: php, local-storage, session-variables

I am developing an online examination system with php. I have designed a question bank type of a thing so that in the exam each students get random questions from the question bank. Basically it means, if I have 100 questions then for the exam I can randomly pull 60 questions for that paper. And also they pulled randomly.

Problem is when the user refresh the page they will get new random questions each time. I tried to store questions in HTML5 localStorage along with the given answers. So that hoping to load from local storage rather than querying from DB at each page refresh.

Then I realized php is serverside and when a page refresh occurs I cannot load from localStorage to the php script. Some articles said to use ajax. But I cannot figure out how to load data, into the same page when refresh button or F5 pressed. (Yes I tried with onbeforeunload)

**Heres what I have done as a solution**. I have saved loaded questions to $_SESSION and accessing that to keep same questions on a refresh.

**Problems I currently having** although this works for keeping the questions it does not helps to save already marked answers and if user accidently closed the window they can't continue where they have left off.

Any ideas? If you want look at my code please let me know.
Thank you.

**Update** Here is my code

```
    <?php if($_GET['exam_id']!="")
{
    $e_id=decrypt_string($_GET['exam_id']);
    $query_p_exam=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from exam where e_id='".$e_id."'"));
    $category_id=$query_p_exam['category_id'];
    $subcategory_id=$query_p_exam['subcategory_id'];
    $subject_id=$query_p_exam['subject_id'];
    $exam_name=$query_p_exam['exam_name'];
    $exam_duration=$query_p_exam['exam_duration'];
    $neg_mark_status=$query_p_exam['neg_mark_status'];
    $negative_marks=$query_p_exam['negative_marks'];
    $question_limit = $query_p_exam['question_limit'];
    //echo $question_limit;
}
?>
<div class="main-content">  
<br>
<div class="container-fluid padded">
<div class="container-fluid padded">


        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <span class="title"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>&nbsp;Questions</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content scrollable" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto">
                        <div class="box-section news with-icons">
                            <form method='post' id='quiz_form' action="main_result.php">
                                        <table style="width:100%;vertical-align:top"  class="table table-normal">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="vertical-align:top">                     
                                                    <?php 
                                                    if($_SESSION["rows"]){

                                                    $tempArray = $_SESSION["rows"];
                                                    //var_dump($tempArray);

                                                    $total_querstion= $question_limit;
                                                    $timeduration=60000*$query_exam_Name['duration'];
                                                    $i=1;
                                                    $m_e_id=1;

                                                    foreach($tempArray as $result){
                                                        $rows[] = $result;

                                                    ?>

                                                    <!-- DISPLAY QUESTION BEGINS -->
                                                    <div <?php if($i==1){}else{echo 'style="display: none;"';}?> id="<?php echo $m_e_id;?>_<?php echo $i;?>" class="display_question">
                                                    <div class="bradcome-menu qu-pa">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6"> <span class="question"> Question No. <?php echo $i;?></span></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <h4 class="quction"><p><?php echo $result['question'];?></p></h4>

                                                    <?php if($result['typeofquestion']=='Single'){?>
                                                    <table class="answeers" border="0" width="100%">                    
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:10px"><input name="radio_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="A" id="" type="radio"></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $result['option_a'];?>                       </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <input name="radio_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="B" id="" type="radio"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_b'];?>                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <input name="radio_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="C" id="" type="radio"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_c'];?>                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <input name="radio_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="D" id="" type="radio"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_d'];?>                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <?php }
                                                    if($result['typeofquestion']=='Multiple'){?>
                                                    <table class="answeers" border="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td style="width:10px">
                                                    <input name="checkbox_A_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="A" id="" type="checkbox"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_a'];?>                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <input name="checkbox_B_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="B" id="" type="checkbox"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_b'];?>                       </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <input name="checkbox_C_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="C" id="" type="checkbox"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_c'];?>                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <input name="checkbox_D_<?php echo $result['q_id'];?>" value="D" id="" type="checkbox"></td><td>
                                                    <?php echo $result['option_d'];?>                       </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <?php }?>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <!-- DISPLAY QUESTION ENDS -->
                                                    <?php $i++;}
                                                    }else{

                                                    $query_pag_data = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from question where e_id='".$e_id."' and  question_status=1 and c_id='".$category_id."' and s_c_id='".$subcategory_id."' order by rand() LIMIT ".$question_limit);


                                                    $total_querstion= $question_limit;
                                                    $timeduration=60000*$query_exam_Name['duration'];
                                                    $i=1;
                                                    $m_e_id=1;
                                                    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query_pag_data)){
                                                        $rows[] = $result;
                                                    ?>  

                                                    <!-- DISPLAY QUESTION BEGINS -->
                                                    <!-- same code -->                                          
                                                    <!-- DISPLAY QUESTION ENDS -->

                                                    <?php   $i++;
                                                            $_SESSION["rows"] = $rows;
                                                        }

                                                    }

                                                    ?>

                                                    <?php 
                                                    $json = json_encode($rows);
                                                    $_SESSION ['json'] = $json;
                                                        ?>                                                  
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td><div id="prev" class="btn btn-gray "><?php echo constant('TI_PREVIOUS_BUTTON');?></div></td>
                                                    <td><div id="mnext" class="btn btn-gray"><?php echo constant('TI_MARK_FOR_REVIEW_BUTTON');?></div></td>
                                                    <td><div id="next" class="btn btn-gray"><?php echo constant('TI_NEXT_BUTTON');?></div></td>
                                                    <td><div id="clearAnswer" class="btn btn-gray"><?php echo constant('TI_CLEAR_ANSWER_BUTTON');?></div></td>
                                                    <td><div style="float:right"><input id="finish" class="btn btn-green" value="Finish" name="Finish" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo constant('TI_SUBMITALERT_MESSAGE')?>')" type="submit"></div></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="exam_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['exam_id'];?>"> 
                                    </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you post the code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the code. please take a look.

Comment: @Katie Thank you for the advice and I will make myself better at asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the step you followed by using session will work, and regarding the already marked answers, you have to update the database, and get the fresh set.

Answer (score 0):

on first page load then save all question id and user id relation in databse like

```
qid uid ans
1    1   update 
1    5   update 
2    5   update
```

so like this all queuestion are first store with user id in random order and on every answer update this record i think its easy because if user close window or any lights off ,compute off its easy to detect where its left

Eg. if userd answer 3 question then you can detect which have not answer then fetch only those question or any other logic you want to apply it can be easy for you

so database is the best solution because if you are using you are not getting values  if you change the browser or any other issue exist then it will not work.

Comment: I will try that approach. Thanks